# How can I read/write bytes to SD card slot of MC60A?

Tags: sd, at-commands, sdcard

I am working on a clickBoard with MC60 A GSM module from MikroEletronika company.

This clickBoard has two slots: (1) one for SIM card and another (2) for micro SD cards. I have read all the available documentation: AT commands  user guide manual (Quectel documentation) and some code examples (Libstock) and i still cannot find any information about how can I communicate with SD card slot.

The only thing I've found about this topic was on quectel hardware guide:

> The following are the main features of SD card interface: 
>   - Only supports 1bit serial mode; Not support the SPI mode for SD memory card
>   - No support multiple SD memory cards
>   - No support hot plug; The data rate up to 48MHz in serial mode
>   - Support for memory cards with maximum capacity up to 32GB;

From this I assume it is a serial communication. So, with the info I know, the two questions I have are:

1. Can I write/read bytes with the usage of AT commands? If yes, which AT commands?
2. It is necessary any specific format for micro SD card (FAT, exFAT, FAT32 or NFTS)?

Comment: You will most likely have to pursue this directly with the manufacturer.

Comment: I already did it. I am just waiting for an answer. Soon as i know how to solve the problem, I'll post here.

Comment: SD Cards have nothing to do with AT-Commands.

Comment: Do some research before comment. If you know what a MC60 is, and if you read my question, you will notice that MC60 has a SD slot card which can be accessed by AT Commands.

Answer (score 1):

I sent an e-mail to quectel manufacturer and they sent me a specific document for FILE AT commands. [Here](https://www.quectel.com/UploadImage/Downlad/Quectel_GSM_FILE_AT_Commands_Manual_V1.4.pdf). For some reason, neither MikroEletronica or quectel have this file available on MC60 datasheets.